# How can I change BNE instruction to BEQ and change its argument?

Tags: arm, disassembly, cracking

I have the following code after disassembling an arm program. How can I change `bne` instruction to `beq` in binary of this program? And how can I change `bne` jump offset?

```
e50b0008        str     r0, [fp, #-8]
e50b100c        str     r1, [fp, #-12]
e51b3008        ldr     r3, [fp, #-8]
e353000d        cmp     r3, #13
1a000001        bne     28 <main+0x28>
e3a03007        mov     r3, #7
ea000000        b       2c <main+0x2c>
e3a03002        mov     r3, #2
e1a00003        mov     r0, r3
```

Comment: you read the documentation on the file format yes?  and the arm documentation on the instruction set?

Comment: @old_timer No, I haven't read it, I was doing things similarly to x86 disassembling and cracking. Can you please give me a link, because I tried searching docs and haven't found anything, that could help me. I found a table with instructions in "ARM Instruction Set" and there said that code for eq is 0000 and for ne is 0001, but I can't understand which bytes I should change. Maybe problem is about I don't know something about byte order.

Comment: infocenter.arm.com.  generally start at arm.com there is a significant amount of info out there, easy to find.  arm.com being the obvious starting point.  x86 is the same story you want to do this in x86 you start by getting intel docs from intel.

Comment: what file format is the binary?  and you googled that already yes?

Comment: if you have a reference manual and this disassembly then it is trivial to see these bit patterns in the manual.  then when you examine the file you can reference this disassembly and the offset/address and see the bytes and the order they are stored in the file.

Comment: the information is all out there, easy to find, you just need to put a little effort in to manipulate the file.  if nothing else you can just search the file for the bytes you see in the disassembly and then try modifying them and see what happens if there is a checksum, etc that you need to patch, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I got an answer for question about how to change `beq` to `bne`. I compiled and disassembled this C code (maybe it's not the best solution, but I was experimenting and it's just for disassembling):

```
int f(int i) {
    if (i == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    return i + f(i - 1);
}

int max(int a) {
    int res = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < a * 2; i++) {
        if (i % 3 != a % 2) {
            res += f(i);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Here if you change `i % 3 != a % 2` to `i % 3 == a % 2`, difference between disassembled codes will be:

```
26c26
<   40: e3a02000    mov r2, #0
---
>   40: e3a0c000    mov ip, #0
28c28
<   48: e15e0002    cmp lr, r2
---
>   48: e15e000c    cmp lr, ip
33,34c33,34
<   5c: e2822001    add r2, r2, #1
<   60: e1520004    cmp r2, r4
---
>   5c: e28cc001    add ip, ip, #1
>   60: e15c0004    cmp ip, r4
36,39c36,39
<   68: e0813295    umull   r3, r1, r5, r2
<   6c: e3c13001    bic r3, r1, #1
<   70: e08330a1    add r3, r3, r1, lsr #1
<   74: e0423003    sub r3, r2, r3
---
>   68: e0823c95    umull   r3, r2, r5, ip
>   6c: e3c23001    bic r3, r2, #1
>   70: e08330a2    add r3, r3, r2, lsr #1
>   74: e04c3003    sub r3, ip, r3
41,44c41,44
<   7c: 1afffff6    bne 5c <max+0x30>
<   80: e3520000    cmp r2, #0
<   84: 11a03002    movne   r3, r2
<   88: 13a01000    movne   r1, #0
---
>   7c: 0afffff6    beq 5c <max+0x30>
>   80: e35c0000    cmp ip, #0
>   84: 11a0300c    movne   r3, ip
>   88: 13a02000    movne   r2, #0
46c46
<   90: e1a0c003    mov ip, r3
---
>   90: e1a01003    mov r1, r3
48c48
<   98: e081100c    add r1, r1, ip
---
>   98: e0822001    add r2, r2, r1
50,53c50,53
<   a0: e2811001    add r1, r1, #1
<   a4: e2822001    add r2, r2, #1
<   a8: e1520004    cmp r2, r4
<   ac: e0800001    add r0, r0, r1
---
>   a0: e2822001    add r2, r2, #1
>   a4: e28cc001    add ip, ip, #1
>   a8: e15c0004    cmp ip, r4
>   ac: e0800002    add r0, r0, r2
57c57
<   bc: e3a01001    mov r1, #1
---
>   bc: e3a02001    mov r2, #1
```

And I think, that `0afffff6    beq 5c <max+0x30>` and `1afffff6    bne 5c <max+0x30>` is what I need. So, we just need to change `0a` to `1a`. Considering byte order, one of the solutions on python3 will be:

```
# I need it if there are more 1a000001 fragments.
pref = b"\x0d\x00\x53\xe3"
suff = b"\x07\x30\xa0\xe3"

# source is file, which code is disassembled
with open("source", mode="rb") as rfile:
    with open("cracked", mode="wb") as wfile:
        data = rfile.read()
        data = data.replace(pref + b"\x01\x00\x00\x1a" + suff, pref + b"\x01\x00\x00\x0a" + suff)

        wfile.write(data)
```